# How get the const and put in mysql database

Tags: javascript, html, fingerprintjs2

I'm using FingerprintJS to get the ID of a user, and right now, I'm only able to output the ID in the console. How can I add the result to a table?

Here's my code:

```
// Initialize the agent at application startup.
const fpPromise = import('https://fpcdn.io/v3/Xhk2W83F3F8jStNRz99k')
  .then(FingerprintJS => FingerprintJS.load())
  
// Get the visitor identifier when you need it.
fpPromise
  .then(fp => fp.get())
  .then( Result  => {
    // This is the visitor identifier:
    const visitorId =  Result.visitorId
    console.log(visitorId)
  })
```

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: A `const` is a regular variable.

Comment: @code just simple with id and the VisitorID

Comment: @ethry so what i need to do?

Comment: Can you show the HTML for your table?

Comment: @code you mean sql?

Comment: Wait a minute, are you running NodeJS or browser JavaScript? You (basically) can't access (or change) SQL databases in the frontend.

Comment: @code so how can i do that in backend?

Comment: @JonesMoura please ask another question for that.

Comment: You'll... need a backend. You might consider PHP, NodeJS, or Python.